# Asymptotic order of the square of the modulus of the second derivative of the Dirichlet kernel in zero

Tags: complex-analysis, dirichlet-series

Consider the Dirichlet kernel $D_N(x)=\sum_{|k|\le N} e^{ikx}$. Its second derivative reads as $$D_N^{\prime\prime}(x) = -\sum_{|k|\le N} e^{ikx}k^2.$$

What is the asymptotic order of $|D_N^{\prime\prime}(0)|^2$ as $N \to \infty$ ?

My attempt:

$$|D_N^{\prime\prime}(x)|^2 = \sum_{|k|\le N} |e^{ikx} |^2 k^4 + 2 \sum_{|k|\le N} \sum_{h \neq k} |e^{ikx} | |e^{ihx} |  k^2 h^2 \cos (kx-hx)  $$ $$= \sum_{|k|\le N}   k^4 + 2 \sum_{|k|\le N} \sum_{h \neq k}   k^2 h^2 \cos (kx-hx)$$

Hence, for $x=0$,
$$|D_N^{\prime\prime}(0)|^2 =   \sum_{|k|\le N}   k^4 + 2 \sum_{|k|\le N} \sum_{h \neq k}   k^2 h^2,  $$ where

$$\sum_{|k|\le N}   k^4 = 2 \sum_{k=1}^N   k^4 = O(N^5),$$

$$\sum_{|k|\le N} \sum_{h \neq k}   k^2 h^2  =4 \sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{h \neq k}   k^2 h^2 + 2\sum_{k=1}^N     k^4 .  $$

Focus on $\sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{h \neq k}   k^2 h^2$. The latter can be rewritten as

$$\sum_{k=2}^N \sum_{h=1}^{k-1}   k^2 h^2+ \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \sum_{h = k+1}^N   k^2 h^2 $$
$$=\sum_{k=2}^N k^2 \sum_{h=1}^{k-1}    h^2+ \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} k^2 \left(\sum_{h = 1}^N     h^2  - \sum_{h = 1}^k     h^2\right)$$
$$=\sum_{k=2}^N k^2 \frac{1}{6} k(k-1)(2k-1)+ \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} k^2 \frac{1}{6}\left(  N(N+1)(2N+1) -  k(k+1)(2k+1) \right)$$
$$ \sim  \frac{1}{3} \sum_{k=2}^N k^5 + \frac{1}{3} N^3\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} k^2 - \frac{1}{3} \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} k^5  = -\frac{1}{3} +\frac{1}{3}N^5 + \frac{1}{3} N^3 \frac{1}{6}N(N-1)(2N-1) = O(N^6).$$

So, finally, $|D_N^{\prime \prime}(0)|^2 = O(N^6)$.

Is my attempt fully correct?

I am puzzled by the fact that the leading term seems to be $\sum_{|k|\le N} \sum_{h \neq k}   k^2 h^2$  and not $\sum_{k=1}^N   k^4$.

Comment: $$
\left| {D_N''(0)} \right| =\sum\limits_{k = -N}^N {k^2 } = 2\sum\limits_{k = 1}^N {k^2 }  = \frac{1}{3}N(N + 1)(2N + 1)
$$

Comment: Straight to the point. Thanks.